# SAS keep tracking of the maximum value of a variable

Tags: variables, sas

I have the following SAS table:

```
ID  Points
01    34
02    14
03    39
04    11
05    55
...
```

I'd like to create another variable that flags the maximum Points value. The expected output is therefore:

```
ID  Points  MaxPoint
01    34       34
02    14       34
03    39       39
04    11       39
05    55       55
...
```

How could I achieve this variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data have;
input ID Points;
datalines;
01 34
02 14
03 39
04 11
05 55
;

data want;
   set have;
   if Points > maxpoints then maxpoints = points;
   retain maxpoints;
run;
```

Comment: It return Maxpoints as a column of "."

Comment: Then either your Points variable is not actually named 'points' or it contains all missing values :-)

Comment: Make sure there does not already exist a maxpoints variable in HAVE.  If so it will overwrite the calculated and retained value.

Comment: And make sure you're not doing this : `data want; set want;`